# How to change the styling of the NativeBase Toast component's close IconButton?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I cannot find a way to change the style the IconButton of the `status: 'error'` [Toast component in native base v3](https://docs.nativebase.io/toast), which under the hood is using an IconButton component.

[Here is the link to the main Toast functions](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/components/composites/Toast/Toast.tsx) such as `useToast` and their props

The simplified code to render a toast looks like the following:

```js
import { useToast } from 'native-base';
...
const Toast = useToast():
...
Toast.show({
  title: 'title',
  status: 'error',
  style: { backgroundColor: 'blue.200' },
})
```

But how would I increase the padding of the close icon button for example? It would be nice to do something like

I understand I can use the [render prop to render a custom component](https://docs.nativebase.io/toast#h3-custom-component), but I would prefer to use the default styling from native base and my extended theme - instead of having to style and render a component that looks exactly the same as the current Toast. This poses an issue if there are default style changes from native base or the app's extended theme, as changes would have to be hardcoded and changed in this render fn as well. Which is not practical!

```js
Toast.show({
  style: {
    _icon: {
      padding: 10,
    },
  }
  // or
  iconButtonStyle: { padding: 10 },
})
```

I can extend the theme and set a default style for IconButton component like so, but this would change every single IconButton in the app - which is not practical.

```js
const myTheme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    IconButton: {
      baseStyle: {
        rounded: 'full',
        padding: 10,
      },
    },
  ...
```

Is it possible to change the base styles like so?

```js
const myTheme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Toast: {
      baseStyle: {
        _icon: {
          padding: 10,
       },
      },
    },
  ...
```

It would be great to know how to change the styling of either:

1. the icon button of one specific Toast component (like in `toast.show()` above)
2. or the default styling for the close icon button of all Toast's, but not other IconButtons

Thanks!